# Let us subdivide $n$ persons into $m$ teams. How often we must rebuild the teams that everyone worked at least once with everyone else in a team?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

We need to subdivide $n$ persons into $m$ teams of equal size ($m\mid n$). How often we must rebuild the teams (by shuffling the team members / reassigning them to a different team) so that everyone worked at least once with every other person in a team?

How do we (re-)form the teams in a structured manner most efficiently?

As an example consider a group of 16 persons that need to be subdivided into 4 teams. How many rounds of teamwork (with reformed teams) we need, if we want to ensure that every person at least worked with every other person?

Comment: What you are asking is similar to the social golfer problem, SGP. The only difference is that SGP is _maximizing_ the number of shufflings while _avoiding repeats_ of players playing together, while your problem is about _minimizing_ the number shufflings while _covering all pairs_.

Comment: Thank you very much: Using your hint, I could solve the problem (which I will post now).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint of Mike Earnest, the problem could straightforwardly be solved.
We need to model the problem as Social Golfer Problem (SGP) of the form $g-s-w=4-4-5$. This special case, also known as *Resolvable Steiner Quadruple System (RSQS)* has the solutions:

1. Round 1: ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP
2. Round 2: AEIM BFJN CGKO DHLP (first Shuffle)
3. Round 3: AFKP BELO CHIN DGJM (second Shuffle)
4. Round 4: AGLN BHKM CEJP DFIO (third Shuffle)
5. Round 5: AHJO BGIP CFLM DEKN (fourth Shuffle)

See also

http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html or

https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/

Comment: Just for fun: this special case of $4$ teams of $4$ people each, or more generally $n$ teams of $n$ people each, is also a [finite affine plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)#Finite_affine_planes). These exist whenever $n$ is a prime power, and if such a plane exists, then you get the additional property that any pair of people only were teammates once.

Comment: Is there a general formula for number of shuffles for $n$ people and $m$ groups?

Comment: @jonnybolton16 Even the case where $n=m^2$ is a hard open problem. In this case, at least $n+1$ shuffles are necessary, yet $n+1$ shuffles is only possible when there exists an affine plane of order $n$, which is an open problem when $n$ is composite and greater than $10$.